# Refresh Events In Angular Calendar UI (Fullcalendar) With Laravel As A Backend

Tags: angularjs, laravel, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am trying to make an automated refresh calendar. I am using Calendar UI and i am getting data from my backend in this way

```
  /**Calendar Config***/
      //config object
                $scope.uiConfig = {
                    calendar:{
                        height: 500,
                        width: 800,
                        editable: false,
                        //First Hour
                        firstHour: 8,
                        //Devide by half hour
                        slotMinutes: 30,
                        //default duration 01:30
                        defaultEventMinutes: 90,
                        axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
                        timeFormat: {
                            agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'
                        },
                    header:{
                        //Buttons
                        center: 'month agendaWeek agendaDay',
                        left: 'title',
                        right: 'today prev,next'
              },
              defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
            }
          };

      //Get planings By Group
            $scope.getPlaningsByGroup = function(groupId){
                planing.getPlaningsByGroup(groupId)
                    .success(function(data){
                        //Populate the event object
                        $scope.populatePlan(data);
                    });
                }

      //Populating the plan
      $scope.events = [];
      $scope.populatePlan = function(plans){
        plans.forEach(function(plan){
          start_time = moment.duration(plan.start_time);;
          duration = moment.duration(plan.course.duration);
          start_course = moment()
                          .day(plan.day)
                          .hour(start_time.hours())
                          .minutes(start_time.minutes())
                          .seconds(start_time.seconds())
                          .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");



          end_time = start_time.add(duration);
          end_course = moment()
                          .day(plan.day)
                          .hour(end_time.hours())
                          .minutes(end_time.minutes())
                          .seconds(end_time.seconds())
                          .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");

          console.log(end_course);

          $scope.events.push(
                  {
                    id:plan.id,
                    title:plan.course.title,
                    start:start_course,
                    end :end_course,
                    allDay:false,
                  }
            );


        });
      }
      //Event Source object
      $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

I don't know if it is the wierdest way to do it but i am still a babe at angular js so please excuse this crime scene ^^ . i did a little reasearch and i decided to go with $interval provider to refresh the events. and here is the problems that i faced after trying:
Try 1 : 
`//Refresh events
          var refresh = function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            console.log("refreshed");
          }
          $interval(refresh, 3000);
          refresh();`

Basically this did nothing 
Try 2 :
`//Refresh events
          var refresh = function(){
            $scope.events.length = 0;
            $scope.getPlaningsByGroup($scope.student.group_id);
            console.log("refreshed");
          }
          $interval(refresh, 3000);
          refresh();`

And this worked but i know that this is a suicide attempt to the backend.
My Question is how to solve this madness. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want refresh existing client side events or keep calendar in sync with server?

Comment: I want to keep it in sync with the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two strategies to keep your calendar in sync with server without make lots of requests.

The first one, is called [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). Put it simply, client makes a request, your server will keep it alive until new events are available.

The second one, is called [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). It's a full-duplex communication channel where you can send data in both directions.

I don't work with PHP, so I don't know if laravel has support for long polling or websocket, but I think that would not be difficult to create.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate it. I think the solution now is to go and learn about one of those approaches.